# CSS Controlling Cascade

Tags: html, css

I have built an editor for users to use, it has a pallette of styles to choose from, for this example we'll call these `.p1` and `.p2'. The problem i have is that they are overriding each other depending on what order they appear in the style sheet.

I cant find a way that is going to solve this, because i do not know how these panels may be nested.

*This example is significantly simplified, and I cannot control exactly where things like the a tag will be, they could be nested in tables, lists, paragraphs, or any other tags, at any depth. This would also apply to headings and any other child elements that need there style customized (eg H1, ul...) to look good in the context that it is shown in.*

```css
.p1 a {
  color: red;
}
.p2 a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="pl p2">
  <a href="#">Hello 2</a>
  <div class="pl p1">
    <a href="#">Hello 2-1</a>
    <div class="pl p2">
      <a href="#">Hello 2-1-2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pl p1">
  <a href="#">Hello 1</a>
  <div class="pl p2">
    <a href="#">Hello 1-2</a>
    <div class="pl p1">
      <a href="#">Hello 1-2-1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have played around with :not selector, and also using all:default, on children, but have had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a little confusing because it has 2 classes applied to the same element.

If I understand you correctly, you want that the *a* element is styled by the **nearest** ancestor in the DOM.

If this is the case, the solution would be to set a set of rules, where the ancestors that have one of the 2 classes will always match, and so the rule with the highest specifity will win....

Sorry, but I can't find a better way to explain it...

```css
.p1 a, 
*[class^=p] .p1 a, 
*[class^=p] *[class^=p] .p1 a, 
*[class^=p] *[class^=p] *[class^=p] .p1 a 
{
 background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.p2 a, 
*[class^=p] .p2 a, 
*[class^=p] *[class^=p] .p2 a, 
*[class^=p] *[class^=p] *[class^=p] .p2 a 
{
 background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="p2">
  <a href="#">Hello 2</a>
  <div class="p1">
    <a href="#">Hello 2-1</a>
    <div class="p2">
      <a href="#">Hello 2-1-2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="p1">
  <a href="#">Hello 1</a>
  <div class="p2">
    <a href="#">Hello 1-2</a>
    <div class="p1">
      <a href="#">Hello 1-2-1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is similar to what I was heading towards

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what you may be looking for is the direct child selector `>`. Learn more about the direct child selector [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

**Live Demo:**

```css
.p1 > a {
  color: red;
}
.p2 > a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="pl p2">
  <a href="#">Hello 2</a>
  <div class="pl p1">
    <a href="#">Hello 2-1</a>
    <div class="pl p2">
      <a href="#">Hello 2-1-2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pl p1">
  <a href="#">Hello 1</a>
  <div class="pl p2">
    <a href="#">Hello 1-2</a>
    <div class="pl p1">
      <a href="#">Hello 1-2-1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot control where that a tag will be, it may be in a list, or a table, or paragraph, or nested in something completely different.

Comment: @cseufert if you donot want the above solution then you can add classes `.forP1` and `.forP2` to the `<a>`. So you can write `p1 .forP1 {...}` and `p2 .forP2 {...}`. This is what you can do.